# Make 15m and 30m mean statistics on influxDB

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I am using Grafana+influxDB. I failed to calculate the mean measurement of last 15m, last 30m.

For example, I have a serial, like:

```
time                                           hash               ip          
2018-05-31T09:21:47.248+08:00 1           11.53433609008789  192.168.1.101
2018-05-31T09:21:48.248+08:00 1           12.53433609008789  192.168.1.102
...
```

What I'd like to print is last 15min, last 30min's hash means. The sample result should be:

```
ip                               last-15min        last-30min
192.168.1.101                     11                   12
192.168.1.102                     11                    18
....
```

How can I achieve it? Thanks. The influxDB version is `1.5.2`

Answer (score 0):

To plot the mean in 15 min / 30 min steps in a simple graph you can use something like:

```
SELECT mean("hash") FROM "enterYourName" WHERE ("ip" = "192.168.1.101") AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time(15m) fill(null)
```

If you only want to display the last mean value in a singlestat panel you can use the above query and set `Options/Values/Stat` to `Current`.